# What is the Access IP Parameter in AWS Data Lake Solution Cloud Formation Template?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, data-lake

I'm a newbie in AWS and I'm trying to deploy the model data lake solution on AWS by following this : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/solutions/latest/data-lake-solution/deployment.html

To deploy the cloud formation template, it asks for an Access IP address. What is the IP address that is required here? Is it the IP address of the machine I'm using to connect to AWS ? I'm connecting through a DHCP network hence the IP address will change the next time I connect to the network.

Appreciate if someone can please clarify this.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like it's a whitelisted IP address that allows an administrator (you) access to the Elasticsearch cluster (ES and Kibana).

You should set it to [your public IP address](https://whatismyipaddress.com/), not a private, DHCP-sourced address. If your public IP changes frequently then you can do a CloudFormation update with the new public IP address. If you don't want to provide access to the cluster directly then you might have to edit the templates to remove this feature.